# Particle Swarm Optimization: what means gBest value?

Tags: matlab, particle-swarm, collective-intelligence

I am designing a Particle Swarm Optimization simulator for MATLAB and I have a doubt about the gBest local position.

As I understood reading about the algorithm, gBest value identify the global best value that has EVER discovered by the particles. However, I saw in a pretty bearable implementation that the developer considered gBest as the best value encountered by the particles in the CURRENT generation.

Have I misunderstood the PSO algorithm basics? Was the developer wrong in his implementation or, however, was it just another different approach?

Thanks in advance,
Víctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to fine tune the PSO , but the [classical algorithm of the PSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization#Algorithm) uses `gBest` as the **swarm best known position**, therefore it is not from current iteration only. In your algorithm you have to implement a memory of some sort in order to calculate the delta used in the velocity update:

[image: delta]

Note that I called `pbest` as the particle best known position and `sbest` the swarm best known position (your gBest). `c1` and `c2` are the confidence levels in the particle itself and in the swarm.